# Smart contract storage doen't work with ganache

Tags: solidity, testrpc, ganache

I have this smart contract

```
contract Ballot {

    struct Prop {
        uint votes;
        bytes32 data;
        address[] validators;

    }

   mapping (bytes32 => Prop) props;
   function addProp(address [] validators, bytes32 data ) public returns(bytes32) {
       var pHash = keccak256(data);
       var newProp = props[pHash];
       newProp.data = data;
       newProp.validators = validators;

       return(pHash);

   }

   function getProp (bytes32 pHash) public constant returns (uint, bytes32, address[]){
       var newProp = props[pHash];
       return(newProp.votes, newProp.data, newProp.validators);
   }

   function voteTo(bytes32 pHash) public {
        var newProp = props[pHash];
        newProp.votes = newProp.votes+1;

   }
}
```

when I add prop and vote for it I can get it's updated data using javascript VM and ropsten, but it doesnt work using testrpc or **ganache**

Comment: Care to give more details? What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Transactions fail, or return invalid data. How do you compile your contracts? You are using "var" and "constant" that are deprecated.

Comment: when I "addProp" then "vote" and then "getProp" I don't get the right value like the state is didnt change

Comment: Are you sure `addProp` completed successfully? It might have run out of gas. I've tried your contract and it does work as expected, `addProp` required above 90k gas to run.

Comment: Show your javascript code.

Comment: I am using remix IDE.